# Is there only one Emerald Herald?

Tags: dark-souls-2

When you meet [Shanalotte](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Emerald+Herald) in Dragon Aerie she says "it was my own manifestation that led you here." You'll also meet her (or her "manifestations") in at least Majula, Drangleic Castle, Undead Crypt and Throne of Want. Are these all tied to the same life? That is, if you kill her in any one of these locations (and *can* she be killed in all of them?), does she stop showing up in all the others?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's only one Shanalotte and if you kill her she won't show up in other places. She works the same as other NPCs as far as death goes.

[Unused dialogue and assets](http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/unused-content) suggest the game originaly had time travel shenanigans so that probably explains why she seems so cryptics at times but since that didn't make it in the final version of the game, she's pretty much "normal".

Comment: Which of the unused content suggests this? I can't find anything in the dialogue about time travel.

Comment: Ah, sorry I didn't mean to link to the dialogue specifically. Theres was some early talk with the developpers and I think some more information in the art book, nothing I can really link right now. There's an unused model of Shanalotte as a child and some early concepts had the Ashen Mist Heart areas be explained as time travel... It's nothing official though.

Comment: [Dark souls 2 focuses heavily on the whole "Time is convoluted" theme.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/259685/is-the-chosen-undead-the-same-person-in-both-dark-souls-and-dark-souls-2/259969#259969). Unfortunately, the Development of this game wasn't quite as polished as it could have been, hence the holes in the plot